# Delete second value in list thats in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that contains many other inner lists, and some of these inner lists contain two values. I want to delete all of the second values in the inner list.

```
[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f', 'g']]
```

Can I use rsplit() for this or are there any other split function that is better to use?

Comment: `[sublist[:1] for sublist in lists]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't care about doing it in-place:

```
>>> outer = [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f', 'g']]
>>> outer = [inner[:1] for inner in outer]
>>> outer
[['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['e'], ['f']]
```

I create a new list using a list comprehension, that contains slices of one element of the original inner lists.

If you need to do it in-place:

```
for inner in outer:
    if len(inner) > 1:
        del inner[1]
```

Comment: `outer[:] = [inner[:1] for inner in outer]` would also be *in-place*y.. (doind `id(outer)` before and after the assignment will return the same value, references to the old `outer` list will update too, a.s.o)

Comment: It would not be in-place. Yes, the reference would afterwards point to that new list, but _other_ references to the old `outer` will not be updated. Do `old = outer = [[...` and then `outer = [inner[:1]...]`, then print `old`: it's the old contents.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw the element and drop them you can use the pop method :

```
list_list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f', 'g']
for my_list in list_list:
    if len(my_list) > 1:
        my_list.pop(1)
```

EDIT: Bad choice for my variable name

Comment: `list` is a bad variable name; it shadows the Python built-in

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using map functions

```
alist = [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f', 'g']]
reducedlist = list(map((lambda x: x[:1]), alist))
print(reducedlist)
```

This is creating a new list from the existing. Iterating over the list and deleting would be the best approach if you want to do it in-place

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving your goal:

```
big_list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f', 'g']]
big_list = [sub_list[0] for sub_list in big_list]
print(my_list)
```

Output:
`['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f']`

Or:

```
big_list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e'], ['f', 'g']]
new_list = list()

for item in big_list:
    new_list.append(item[0])

print(new_list)
```

Output: 
`['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f']`

Comment: a bit more creativity in the naming of the variables wouldn't harm ☺

Comment: I added creativity to the names.